# ShellExecute in C++ on VSE (visual studio enterprise) 2015 doesn't works

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw

When i'm trying to run my code, writed in c++ on visual studio, ShellExecute doesen't show me the  ipconfig and also doesn't start chrome. I have not any warning or error.The problem it's about the cmd called by ShallExecute, it starts but it stop immediatly, I had the same problem with VS but i added the `stdafx.h` header.Also Chrome neither starts. I write the same code on a file and I run it, compiled by g++, on mingw, and it works. So this is the code on visual studio :

**VS PROJECT**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WINPAUSE system("pause")
#endif

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            cout << "\t" << i << "\t dispari!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "\t" << i << "\t dispari!!!" << endl;
    }
    ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("cmd"), _T(" /C ipconfig"), _T(" C:\ "), SW_SHOW);
    cout << "\nLancio google.com" << endl;
    string google = "https://www.google.it/search?as_q=";
    string ricerca = "";
    cout << "Inserisci la tua ricerca su google :" << endl;
    getline(cin, ricerca);
    google += ricerca;
    ShellExecute(0, 0,(LPCWSTR)google.c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
    cout << "Tutto andato a buon fine" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code on the file(I dont add the part of ipconfig)

**first.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <string>

#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            cout << "\t" << i << "\t dispari!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "\t" << i << "\t dispari!!!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nLancio google.com" << endl;
    string google = "https://www.google.it/search?as_q=";
    string ricerca = "";
    cout << "Inserisci la tua ricerca su google :" << endl;
    getline(cin, ricerca);
    google += ricerca;
    ShellExecute(0, 0,(LPCSTR)google.c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
    cout << "Tutto andato a buon fine" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For any question or uncleard concept ask me .

UPDATE : Here a **solution**, it seems to work

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    ShellExecute(0, 0, L"cmd.exe", L"/k help", 0, SW_SHOW);
    cout << "\nLancio google.com" << endl;
    wstring google = L"https://www.google.it/search?as_q=";
    wstring ricerca = L"";
    cout << "Inserisci la tua ricerca su google :" << endl;
    wcin >> ricerca;
    google += ricerca;
    LPCWSTR googlata = google.c_str();
    ShellExecute(NULL , L"open", L"chrome.exe", googlata, 0, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: There is a remark for ShellExecute in [MSDN][1] that you might need to use CoInitializeEx. Maybe this will help?

  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are several issues.

First, in Windows Vista and Windows 7 `ipconfig` required privilege elevation. To do that via `ShellExecute` you can use the `runas` verb. Then if UAC, User Access Control, is enabled, you'll get a silly warning box asking you to confirm that you really want to run the dangerous `ipconfig` program.

That is, if you run it directly, and not via `cmd`, as your current code needlessly attempts.

But, third, the result of running a console program directly is usually a console window that pops up and disappears when the console program finishes. And for this involving `cmd` can do the job. Just use the `/k` option to `cmd`, which tells it to *keep* after executing the specified command.

Fourth, there's a lot of Microsoft `_T` stuff in that code. It's been obsolete since the year 2000. For modern Windows just use wide character strings, e.g. `L"Hello!"`.

Fifth, the C cast in

```
(LPCWSTR)google.c_str()
```

***Never do that***.

You're telling the compiler to shut up because, you're saying, you know better. But you absolutely don't. `google` is a simple `std::string`, and you're casting to wide character string, `wchar_t const*`. That will never work.

Again, in modern Windows just use wide character text. That means wide literals like `L"Hello!"`, and wide strings like `wstring`. Define the macro symbol **`UNICODE`** before including `<windows.h>` (apparently it is defined in your VS project, since the call with the cast in it compiles, but still).

---

In other news, not about the code's correctness, but just advice:

- For a Windows-specific program `#ifdef _WIN32` doesn't make sense: `_WIN32` is always defined, also in 64-bit Windows. So you can simplify that.
- The `"stdafx.h"` header is a convention used by Visual Studio for a precompiled header. Visual C++ precompiled headers change the preprocessing semantics, in particular that that header must be included first of all in every translation unit, which has tripped up many beginners. I strongly advice you to just turn off precompiled headers in the project settings, and remove the include (in a much larger project it can be worth checking if precompiled headers reduce build times enough to take the penalty of non-standard rules).
- Instead of declaring variables that are modified you can often declare `const`-ants that are combined in expressions. That makes it easier to understand or prove the code, because there's less that can change. Just sprinkle `const` generously just about everywhere you can.

Comment: Perfect, I did it, please also check if is a valid solution.